# Manual php script execution works while execution via debian fails

Tags: php, curl, ssh, cron, webmin

I have a problem with running the script using scheduled cron jobs. The thing is that when I run the php script using the browser it is executed without any problems/failures etc.
But when I try to run it using crons or SSH I get weird errors:

> Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/loves/public_html/parser/shop_parse_class.php on line 125
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in /home/loves/public_html/parser/shop_parse_class.php on line 481
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /home/loves/public_html/parser/shop_parse_class.php on line 482
>   PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: cat in /home/loves/public_html/parser/shop_parse_class.php on line 538

As you can see from the errors it shows that, for example the option HTTP_USER_AGENT doesn't exist for the CURL, which is kinda weird. Maybe the problem is with the environment variables, however I have poor knowledge of linux system.

Comment: Are you executing the php script via the command line?  If that's the case the http-specific environment PHP normally provides (like `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`) when executed through a website isn't going to exist.

Comment: @Joe This is the option that I set for CURL 
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);`

Comment: This is a PHP notice, not a PHP error.

Comment: @Jocelyn but it fails after this (exits). Because I have the die() command when curl fails to retrieve the page

Comment: As Jocelyn pointed out, these are just notices.  Its very possible that your script has always had the issue that caused them, and when you moved to your new server its configured not to hide them.  They also might have nothing to do with your curl request failing.  If your call to `curl_exec()` is failing and returning false, you should pass your curl handle to [curl_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) and see what it has to say about why it failed.

Comment: If don't really need `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` in `/home/loves/public_html/parser/shop_parse_class.php`, so just use `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `-A` or `--user-agent` parameter to the cURL call.
You can set anything you want as user agent this way.

Comment: I think the problem is he's trying to execute a script written for a website through the commandline, so the normal HTTP environment doesn't exist.  curl normally adds a user-agent string similar to "curl/7.21.6" if an alternative user-agent isn't specified.

Comment: How do I make it a normal HTTP environment then?

Comment: I have a PHP script that I call using cURL and I set an own User Agent so I check that it's my script who does the call, in this way:
curl -A "MyCompanyName cURL" "MyURL.com"

And then, the php script checks it with:
$userAgent = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : null;

Comment: @Jester I am using CURL inside php script not directly.

Comment: @OlegBondarenko Then this is the problem, at that point you don't have  $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] set if you didn't call the php with a browser or with cURL. How did you call it?

Comment: @OlegBondarenko Also, if you don't call it from a browser (that's why you don't have the user agent), you might not want to give cURL the same user agent you get, so you could set an string for the user agent in the curl_setopt: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'WhateverYouNeed');

Comment: Thanks all and especially Jester, it seems that the problem was with the $_SERVER thing

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_USER_AGENT is a information returned by the browser, if you are running like a script, you can't use this array. Is that reason the array is empty (the message tells that the index you trying to use in array don't exists)

Comment: Bruno, maybe you are right. However, the thing is that I had no problems running this script on my previous hosting (through Cpanl/crons), however when I moved to the virtual server hosting with webmin/virtualmin instead of Cpanel I can't seem to get this working.

Comment: In the PHP docs says that information can be empty. Try to verify if isn't null with "isset()" before using the HTTP_USER_AGENT and see if works fine.

Comment: Better, try to use this: array_key_exists('HTTP_USER_AGENT', $_SERVER)